# WPF Checkbox Custom Style Check disappeared

Tags: wpf, checkbox, properties, styles, datatrigger

Maybe this is redundant but I could not find anything.  I probably am missing something simple.

The checkbox in question is set in the codebehind on a selection event

```
  chkEmpOK.IsChecked = _cfgUsr.IsEnabled;
```

This worked as desired until I tried to add a custom style. Now the checkbox displays the text but the image/glyph/box part of the checkbox does not display.  I am assuming I did something wrong in the style.  Here is the control and style from the XAML:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkEmpOK" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Margin="10,10,0,0">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Click Me to Enable"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="To remove access- click me"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

This is what it looks like
[image: Snippet from UI]

Hopefully I am missing something simple. Does it have anything to do with it inheriting from ToggleButton?

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding original checkbox style with your own that has no code related to box. Navigate to **Document Outline** window, right click on your checkbox and then Edit Template -> Edit Copy.

Then you can import template style to window resources and edit it:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                                <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stretch="None"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="2" Opacity="0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="To remove access- click me" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Click Me to Enable" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Edit related triggers as you like:

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="To remove access- click me" />
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Click Me to Enable" />
</Trigger>
```

The other way is yo add your own code for the box.
Like StackPanel with Border and vector image. See example below:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkEmpOK" Margin="10,10,0,0">
        <CheckBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Border Width="15"
                                        Height="14"
                                        BorderThickness="1"
                                        BorderBrush="DimGray"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <Viewbox Margin="1">
                                        <Path
                                            x:Name="ckeckMark"
                                            Fill="Black"
                                            Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " />
                                    </Viewbox>
                                </Border>
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="5 0 0 0" 
                                                  Focusable="False"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Click Me to Enable" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" TargetName="ckeckMark" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="To remove access- click me" />
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="ckeckMark" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </CheckBox.Style>
    </CheckBox>
```

Another approach is to use Checked and Unchecked events to set content and color for your checkbox. If your program is large consider to use MVVM pattern.

Comment: First, thank you. By add your own code I am assuming you mean the other examples where the control template is a Grid or StackPanel and then placing a check or uncheck image plus text in the Control template.

Comment: I've expanded the answer with an example for custom box style. You can use any panel that you think is the best for your case.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to override Template to change Content or Foreground. Style triggers should do:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkEmpOK" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Margin="10,10,0,0">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Click Me to Enable"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="To remove access- click me"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: you are absolutely correct and I like the simplicity of your answer.  In another application I set Triggers for IsChecked (true and false) and IsEnabled (False) setting Content, Foreground, FontWeight and Style and the users were quite happy with the usability.